# click event with angular has to be clicked twice in order to complete action

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm having a problem with my button. The button is a login button. When I click enter after typing credentials, the method to see if the credentials are correct fires off. This works without any problems.

But what is supposed to also happen is, after checking these if the credentials are correct, the login and signup button are supposed to be removed along with a new profile button that will appear.

In order for the previous thing to occur, I have to hit the button a second time for those buttons to disappear.

I'm not really sure what the problem is... here is my code. Hopefully it's not too much. I took out whatever is not necessary.

App.component.html (main component for angular)

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button *ngIf="loggedOff" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Login
  </button>
  <ul *ngIf="loggedOff" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <button class="btn" id="loginButton" type="button" (click)="submit(username.value, pword.value)">
        Go!
      </button>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

App.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  loggedin: boolean;
  loggedOff: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedin = false;
    this.loggedOff = true;
  }
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService,) { }

  submit(username: string, pword: string)
  {
    this.loggedin = this.loginService.signIn(username, pword);
    if(this.loggedin == true)
    {
      this.loggedOff = false;
    }
  }
```

loginService.ts

```
  signIn(username: string, pword: string) : boolean
  {
    let sendData = new FormData();

    this.http.post(this.loginURL, sendData, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res => {
      if(res.includes("Good")){
        this.loginAttempt = true;
      }else
        this.loginAttempt = false;
    });
    return this.loginAttempt;
  }
```

I'm thinking it might have something to do because of the Http call? But, I'm not really sure... I assumed this whole process I'm describing is synchronous.. Maybe it's not?

Comment: In your login service, move the return up. Right now you return 'this.loginAttemlt' right away before the loginAttempt even init. And that why it's working only in the second time

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. move the return up? I think i did that but I'm still getting the same result

Comment: The return statement need to be inside the scope of the subscribe function.

Comment: should loginattempt be an observer?

Comment: In logging service, remove this line 'return this.loginAttempt;' and in the 'if' put 'return true' and in the else put 'return false'

Comment: Right, but  the lmethod signIn returns a boolean to the method submit inside App.component.ts. In the submit method is where I modify the visibility of elements in my html page.

So the only way to modify does elements is by returning a boolean value from the signIn method

Answer (score 1):

As somebody pointed out already, Http calls are asynchronous, so you cannot expect that the value returned from your service will be populated right off the bat.

Instead, you will have to subscribe asynchronously to it from the consumer, which in this case is the component. Refactoring the service and the coponent like this will do the trick:

```
// login.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private loginURL = 'http://...';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  signIn(username: string, password: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.loginURL, { username, password }, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
}

// app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

  submit(username: string, password: string) {
    this.loginService.signIn(username, password).subscribe(res => {
      this.isLoggedIn = res.indexOf('Good' >= 0);
    });
  }
}
```

Do not forget to edit the template accordingly! :)

Comment: Right so the boolean that delegates the login/signup/profile button needs to be an observable to the loginService?

Comment: @JD333 Any call to the `HttpClient` will return an Observable stream. In that sense, the issue with your code is that you were returning `this.loginAttempt` to the consumer component BEFORE it was actually assigned, since the assignation occurs in an asynchronous parallel thread.

Comment: @JD333 did the answer helped solve your issue? If so, please mark it is as solved so others can benefit from it. Thanks :)